# TreeView in windows 8 store app in XAML

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

As I know there is no treeview control in Windows 8 store app, does anyone know an alternative solution?I want to display some parent child data with collapse and expend on click of the header, but this is not possible in GridView and ListView of Windows 8. Can any one help me for this ?

Comment: [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappsuidesign/thread/98ab15dc-65c4-49fb-8ce7-a2d5748a8d7a/) may help, look for Jeff Sanders answer

Comment: Thanks but i am not getting any thing from there. is there any open source or some examples available for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [TreeView control](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c814f6c67c540adbd6952821a351d9ffa4d1d99#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/TreeView/TreeView.cs) in WinRT XAML Toolkit that has been ported from the Silverlight Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Tree Navigator control from Syncfusion WinRT Studio may help to achieve your requirement. It supports hierarchical data binding. It also has two different navigation modes. The control provides a unique interface that can expand a tree structure in-place without taking up more space on the screen.

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/controls

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want free control i guess it is paid.