# Is there a tree like control in WinRT?

Tags: winrt-xaml

I want to display a hierarchical data like treeview which is in Windows 8 Mail box. do you have any suggestion on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TreeView in windows 8 store app in XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977451/treeview-in-windows-8-store-app-in-xaml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this post will answer for your query.

[TreeView in windows 8 store app in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977451/treeview-in-windows-8-store-app-in-xaml). Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fairly thorough discussion in [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/30551) question.

Essentially it looks like MS have decided to scrap the traditional treeview.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [TreeView control](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c814f6c67c540adbd6952821a351d9ffa4d1d99#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/TreeView/TreeView.cs) in WinRT XAML Toolkit that has been ported from the Silverlight Toolkit.